# Scala: good way to keep pairs of strings

Tags: scala, dictionary, set, scala-collections

What is a neat way to hold pairs of strings which are not necessarily key-values (might have duplicate keys), for a small collection? List[List[String]] works obviously but looks dirty.

Cheers
Parsa

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Tuples are the ideal data structure to represent pairs.

So use a list of `(String, String)` tuples.

Answer (score 14):

`List[(String,String)]` is the standard solution:

```
scala> List(("foo","bar"), ("foo","baz"))
res1: List[(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)] = List((foo,bar), (foo,baz))
```

Comment: Exactly! The nice thing about tuples is that equality, pattern matching, etc. works as one would expect. `("foo", "bar") == ("foo", "bar")` returns `true`, for example.

Comment: You also get lexicographic ordering of pairs, which is an extremely nice freebie.

Comment: I came across this nice tuple trick yesterday: http://goo.gl/MT6J. It makes a good use of the fact that all the tuple classes have instances of `Ordering` trait defined for them.